# vertically center text after a left floated image

Tags: html, css, center

```
<img style="float:left" src="image.jpg"> <center>text</center>
<hr style="clear:both">
```

What I want to achieve with the above code is have an image floated to the left, text that is vertically centered (instead of placed at the top like it currently is) and horizontally centered, and then after the image and text there is a horizontal bar to divide both the image and text from the rest of my stuff. I'm not sure how to vertically center the text without doing funky stuff like a table with a single row and column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/fuaVF/2/)

if you have a fixed height for the area in which your image lies then you can give

`line-height = the height of the image` to place the text vertically center

EDIT : [another way](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/fuaVF/4/)

Comment: Almost worked. :( If the text gets long and needs to wrap to a new line, the new line goes under the image instead of directly under the first line of text, since the line height is the height of the image.

Comment: Well, splitting the current div it into two divs would solve that.

Comment: hmm now thats a prob. Sorry this is not a good way enough but  will do the trick. If your text is not gonna change, i mean if its not a dynamic content then try out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/fuaVF/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<img style="float:left" src="image.jpg">text
</div>

img
{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Why not add `<div style="text-align:center;">`? since he wants horizontally centered text.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Note the <hr> bar in my code with the clear:both style. I think the presence of that messes with vertical alignment, but I need the stuff after the text to be cleared so that it doesn't encroach onto the image and text area.